# A clock and a fortune: a full screen clock with random quotes in Tcl/Tk

Tags: beginner, timer, tk, tcl

I've written a small Tcl/Tk script for a friend that displays the current time, as well as a quote. He uses it in some project with a Raspberry Pi, and since I didn't want to cobble up something up in Qt, PyQt, or some kind of website, I tried to write something in Tcl/Tk.

## Demo

Here is how it looks in the end:

[image: screenshot of program]

## Requirements

This script assumes that you have `fortune` available an in your `$PATH`.

## Script

```
#!/usr/bin/env tclsh

proc every {ms body} {
    eval $body
    after $ms [info level 0]
}

label .time -bg black -fg white -font {Arial 150} -textvar ::time -pady 30
every 1000 { set ::time [clock format [clock sec] -format "%T"] }

label .fortune -bg black -fg white -font {Arial 15}  -textvar ::fortune
every 30000 { set ::fortune [exec fortune -s] }

pack .time -fill both
pack .fortune -fill both -expand 1

. configure -bg black

wm attributes . -fullscreen 1

bind . <q> exit
```

## What to review

This is my first script in Tcl/Tk. Feel free to commend on anything, especially if there's some kind of common style I'm missing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nice code. I only see a couple of items

1. add `package require Tk` to be explicit you need tk
2. use `uplevel #0 $body` instead of `eval`

Comment: Ad 1) I had that in the original Raspberry code and another rewrite, completely missed it in my last one. ad 2) can you explain the difference between `uplevel #0 $body` and `eval`?

Comment: `uplevel` evaluates the given code in a particular "stack frame". This is important as each frame the current execution stack will have a different set of (local) variables. The level `#0` is the zero-th level from the bottom of the stack, in other words the global frame. In your programming, you are explicitly setting global variables, so `eval` and `uplevel #0` have identical effects.

Comment: where `uplevel` is really handy is in writing custom loops like `myforeach foo $list {some body here}` where you need to evaluate the loop body 1 level up in the stack frame (where the `myforeach` command invocation resides)

Comment: Is there some kind of style guide? Or does "usual" Tcl code look like mine?